# how to remove box2d maxVelocity?

Tags: box2d

I don't know if there is such a parameter in box2D or not but when I duplicate all the numbers in my scene simulations produce different results, I was just simulating a pendulum (an static box joint to a dynamic box using revolute joint) and when I multiplied all the values in my scene by 32 (to have a same scale with my game), it fall slower than normal condition, (and i've increased gravity too). it seems like when pendulum is falling it reaches some max speed and doesn't go beyond that. so when it's comming back up it reaches half way to the height it started falling from. by the way I think it's not cause by friction because i've set all dumping and friction values to zero and beside this problem didn't apear before scaling my scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the value of b2_maxTranslation in b2Settings.h

Answer (score 0):

Box2d is simulating using iterative solver and the result might be different for different size of objects - it's ok. In manual is written that the best size of simulated dynamic objects is 0.1 - 10 and up 50 for static bodies. Also increasing all sizes will not produce the same movement in a real world. For example imagine a 1 meter radius falling sphere from 100 meter height. Multiplying it's radius and height by 10 for example will obviously give different fall time, because it's only depend on height.

Also I've tried nvidia physx once. I've just created a very simple scene - a cube falling at the plane and bouncing. The cube was one meter at a side. First I was simulating with density of cube 10 and everything was perfect. Then i decided to simulate an iron cube and changed the density to 7200. As you understand the bounce was expected totally the same because the restitution parameter was not change. But the simulation was really ugly - the cube falling into the plane and bouncing ugly. So it's really important to keep the values in a recommended range.

Comment: although you answer seems to be correct, you example about what would happen in reality is a bit wrong, when i say i'll multiply every thing by 10 it means you'll also increase gravity 10 times, it's just like you are changing your calculating unit.for example changing meters to centimeters, will increase all the numbers in your equations 10 times but you'll see the exact same thing happen with these bigger numbers.

Comment: it's still not correct to multiply all values by the same constant. Consider the example you are multiplying force per 10, length per 10, torque per 10. It will not be correct, because torque must be multiplied per 100 in this case. Dimensional analyses is a bit harder. And still even correct rescaling will not provide the same simulation

Comment: Also there is such parameter as linearDamping in b2Body. Possibly this value is not zero by default. Try setting it to zero

Comment: i've already set all damping values to zero (either linear or angual) i was just scaling gravity (m/s^2) and speed(m/s) and position (m) so the result should be same!